# Landsat images request

Tags: r, download, landsat

Is there any way I can automatically make a request by date to USGS to get Landsat 8 images? Actually, I am doing this manually by filing bulk request to USGD through Earthexplorer web interface. In addition, is there an R code I can use to extract information from Landsat 8 images? (I know there is already the Landsat package)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any code or package to download landsat images. But to get information about them, I use the read.metadata function inside the plotKML package.

Here is an example, where I read the azimuth in the .xml data

```
library(plotKML)
meta<-read.metadata(paste(DataPath,"LC82330852015268LGN00.xml",sep=""))
azi=as.numeric(meta$value[9])
```

Hope this is useful for you

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out the [ESPA API](https://github.com/USGS-EROS/espa-api#user-api) from the USGS?  It allows you to request metadata, build orders, etc.  There's a [jupyter notebook demo](https://github.com/USGS-EROS/espa-api/blob/master/examples/api_demo.ipynb) in their repo which will give you a good idea of the capabilities.

You might also be interested in the [USGS/EROS Inventory Service API](https://earthexplorer.usgs.gov/inventory/documentation) for getting metadata about acquisitions to download.

Answer (score 0):

You should check out `rLandsat` package, https://github.com/socialcopsdev/rLandsat, which gives an easy way to request landsat images in R using the ESPA APIs and sat-api.

An example from the package,

```
# get all the product IDs for India, alternatively can define path and row
result = landsat_search(min_date = "2018-01-01", max_date = "2018-01-16", country = "India")

# inputting espa creds
espa_creds("yourusername", "yourpassword")

# getting available products
prods = espa_products(result$product_id)
prods = prods$master

# placing an espa order
result_order = espa_order(result$product_id, product = c("sr","sr_ndvi"),
                          projection = "lonlat",
                          order_note = "All India Jan 2018")
order_id = result_order$order_details$orderid

# getting order status
durl = espa_status(order_id = order_id, getSize = TRUE)
downurl = durl$order_details

# download; after the order is complete
landsat_download(download_url = downurl$product_dload_url, dest_file = getwd())
```